# How to prevent Excel 2013 custom ribbon buttons from disappearing

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, ribbon

I am working with Excel 2013. I've written several macros in Personal Workbook modules. I've created custom buttons in the ribbon to run those macros and everything works fine. Next day I run Excel and the custom buttons are gone. I tried this many times and the result is always the same. Strange thing is that custom buttons that I have created more than a year ago are there and are never removed

I have done some research and it seems that Excel does this for security issues. Is there a way to bypass this button deletion?

Comment: Arrgh, yes there is. I've done it before but can't remember exactly how. I'll rack my brains and hopefully get back to you. But in the mean time, there definitely is a way so don't stop looking.

I *think* I was editing xml so that there was a load occuring on excel launch. But I had to do that as it was via a citrix environment. 

This might be more applicable to you: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/add-in-ribbon-disappears/

Answer (score 2):

VBA macros is not designed for customizing the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in Office applications. For current document you may include a custom ribbon UI into the document. For example, the following articles describe how to do that for Word documents, but the approach is common for Excel and Word documents:

- [OfficeTalk: Customizing the Word 2007 Fluent Ribbon is as Easy as 1-2-3 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2007/cc508991(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [OfficeTalk: Customizing the Word 2007 Fluent Ribbon is as Easy as 1-2-3 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/officetalk2007/cc508991(v=office.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

If you need to distribute your customizations on multiple machines, I'd suggest developing a COM add-in instead, for example, it can be a VSTO add-in. That's what they were invented for. Moreover, you can create a custom UI customizations as a part of the add-in.

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

If you customized the ribbon using file->options, you can see the .officeui file in the below folder, I think this file is not synchronized in your next login, but you can copy to your local, and when it's missing you can copy that officeui file to the %appdata% directory as mentioned below.

%appdata%/Microsoft/office

I recommend you to customize the ribbon in your workbook using CustomUI editor, so that it will retain the customization inside your workbook and not as the separate file (OFFICEUI).